# Is it possible to html import *

Tags: html, polymer

I'm away from my computer right now but was wondering, is it possible to do something like...

```
<link type='import' href='mydir/*'/>
```

Comment: Please, explain in more detail what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I often am in favor of closing unclear questions, but isn't this obvious? The OP wants to import every resource under that path element. It's not possible because (among other things) there's no standard way of listing all resources under a path over HTTP, but it seems like a well formed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how the [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) element works, for imports or anything else. Similar to including CSS and JavaScript, the `href` attribute refers to a URL of the resource you want to import.

Likewise, these do **not** work:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='mydir/css/*' type='text/css'>
<script src='mydir/js/*'></script>
```

You can [read more about HTML imports at HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/). At the moment, browser support is pretty limited, the IE team is [considering support](http://status.modern.ie/htmlimports) for them in the near future.